# how to address a file out of webserver folder in HTML

Tags: html, iis

I have an HTML file in my server. I placed it in a web application in IIS.

I want to place an Image in this page that addresses a file out of web application folder. For example this address:

```
d:\MyImagesFolder\MyImage.jpg
```

But it doesn't show the image in the HTML page.

What's wrong?

Comment: Is it a local server or a web server?

Comment: I have an IIS on my local server.

Comment: Try moving the image to the same directory where you have the server installed (like C: or D: ) I don't know much about IIS, but I believe if your folder is outside the local server it wouldn't be reachable by the server itself... Perhaps I'm wrong, I'm not sure, so you'll need to give it a try.

Comment: I can't move the image folder. because the image folder is for other windows application on the server.

Comment: I might know a way of doing that, but I don't have access to my PC now and I'd need a php script that I don't have right now. I'll try to get back to you tomorrow or Sunday, OK? By the way, happy new year! :)

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Happy new year :)

Comment: Thanks! Hey, I was thinking, a php script will be useless without a server... maybe you'll have to install a local server to your drive D: and then move the images folder to it. Xampp would do the job, then move the images to `htdocs` folder. Can you do that? Or you can't move the images at all?

Comment: formatting code, typos, one question mark is enough

Comment: Well, it would be a huge lack of security trying to access files outside the root of your web application, it's not recommended. It would be better to upload the images to a web server and then get their paths from the server itself (for example, Dropbox, GitHub, etc). Or you could copy the images you need to your app root folder. But if you really need to do that, there's a way by using asp, and you can try following a tutorial I found [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Displaying-images-that-are-stored-outside-the-Website-Root-Folder.aspx), or you can do something else like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any solution for this problem.

Finally I solve my problem in this way. I read the file in back-end and send the Base64 string of the images to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. the image should be in the website folder. then the website can access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, then by using virtual resource (or directory) in IIS, you can access resource out of your website folder but file should be on server